# what does struct_name(0) mean in solidity

Tags: solidity

```
  struct Proposal {                  
        uint voteCount;
    }
 

  for (uint prop = 0; prop < numProposals; prop ++)
            proposals.push(Proposal(0));
```

what does 'Proposal(0)' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposal(0) , means your creating an instance of the data type Proposal. The "0" parameter is actually putting data in the voteCount property of the data type. Henceforth the new created proposal datatypes voteCount is set to 0 now

Here some resources about this :>

- https://solidity-by-example.org/structs/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQJ4TeHifdk&list=PLO5VPQH6OWdVQwpQfw9rZ67O6Pjfo6q-p&index=24